# QSetting and QWidgets class serialization and deserialization

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, pyqt5, qsettings

Having a `QComboBox QWidgets class`, a list contains 5 times `QComboBox QWidgets class`. How could the list with `classes of QWidgets` in `PyQt5` saves and restores (serialize and deserialize) later? 
Could serialization and deserialization be achieved for such classes with `QSetting`, in case the code below is provided!

**COMBO.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
class combo(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(combo, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.cb = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.cb.addItems(["1", "2", "3","4"])
        self.cb.setCurrentIndex(2)
        pal = self.cb.palette()
        pal.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Button, QtGui.QColor(255,255,255))
        self.cb.setPalette(pal)
        layout.addWidget(self.cb)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = combo()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

***Serailization and deserialization***

```
from COMBO import combo
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

def readSettings():
    settings = QtCore.QSettings('file.ini' ,QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)
    settings.beginGroup("LIST")
    # Some code to restore classes
    settings.endGroup()

def writeSettings(CLASSLISTS):
    settings = QtCore.QSettings('file.ini' ,QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)
    settings.beginGroup("LIST")
    # Some code to store classes
    settings.endGroup()   

CLASSLISTS = []

for _ in range(5):
    CLASSLISTS.append(combo())

print(CLASSLISTS)
writeSettings(CLASSLISTS)
```

Comment: You cannot serialize widgets, but you can serialize some of the settings/data they contain. It's up to you to decide which things get saved.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Thinking what about dill and pickle moduls?